# Regular expression using R

Tags: regex, r

How can I write R code to extract all numbers relating to money or percentages using regular expressions in the sentence below. The R code should pick up things like: `39.7 percent`, and dollar values like `$873,599` and `$1 million`.

My sample text is:

> While choice across all price segments was low, interest in top-end homes remained high and 355 properties, or 37.6 percent of all homes sold, attracted a price in excess of $873,599 and $1 million".

I've tried the following `$?[0-9,.]+Percent?Million?` but this isn't working as expected.

Comment: Please provide the R code for your best attempt in a minimal self-contained reproducible fashion.  See [mcve] for more info on how to ask a question.

Comment: I see you are a new poster.  The reason this received heavy down votes is because you provided no data, no code, and the question sounds like you might think of StackOverflow (SO) as a code writing service. You can see these SO guidelines [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It also sounds like reading through a regex tutorial may be useful.  I found [THIS](http://www.rexegg.com/) one to be useful when I was learning.  You're welcomed to re-edit your question if it hasn't been closed by then to comply with StackOverflow expectations.

Answer (score 3):

## Description

`[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s*(?:%|percent)|\$(?:[0-9]{3},)*[0-9]+(?:\s(?:thousand|million|billion|trillion))?`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find all the numbers that represent percents, with or without a decimal point

  - the number may be followed by a `%` sign or the literal word
- find all the numbers that are dollar amounts

  - with a leading dollar sign
  - may include a comma separator
  - may be followed by a word like thousand, million, billion, or trillion
- avoid other non dollar or percent numbers

## Examples

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/uG6mQ4/1

**Sample Text**

> "While choice across 100% price segments was low, interest in top-end homes remained high and 355 properties, or 37.6 percent of all homes sold, attracted a price in excess of $873,599 and $1 million".

**Sample Matches**

```
[0][0] = 100%
[1][0] = 37.6 percent
[2][0] = $873,599
[3][0] = $1 million
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    %                        '%'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    percent                  'percent'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      thousand                 'thousand'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      million                  'million'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      billion                  'billion'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      trillion                 'trillion'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```